# The inequality of an integration

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let $f(x) \le 0$ with $x \in [0,\,x_0]$ and $f(x)>0$ with $x>x_0$. We also assume $\alpha(x)<g(x)<\beta(x)\le0$ with all $x\ge0$. Is the following inequality true ?
$$
\int_0^\infty  {f(x) \cdot g(x)dx}  < \int_0^{{x_0}} {f(x) \cdot \alpha (x)dx}  + \int_{{x_0}}^\infty  {f(x) \cdot \beta (x)dx} 
$$

Comment: Are you comfortable with the monotonicity of the integral (i.e. $f \le g \leadsto \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx \le \int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx$)?

Comment: Thanks ! I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is true. To see this, try thinking about the sizes of the different integrands (including sign) in both regions.